Let youtube video play in the background in expo react native webview app? (like brave browser)
trying to crate a simple browser that should have this feature, playing youtube video in the background. Just like brave browser. Currently it is just an android app. tried this method:
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { AppState } from 'react-native';

const MediaWebView = () => {
  const webViewRef = useRef(null);
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState(AppState.currentState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', (nextAppState) => {
      setAppState(nextAppState);
      if (nextAppState === 'background') {
        // const video = document.querySelector('video'); 
        // video.play()
        // or Force the WebView to be visible
        webViewRef.current?.injectJavaScript(`
          document.body.style.visibility = 'visible';
        `);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
     <WebView
          ref={webViewRef}
          source={{ uri: url }}
          style={styles.webview}
          onNavigationStateChange={handleNavigationStateChange}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          onMessage={onMessage}
          onScroll={handleScroll}
          mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
          allowsFullscreenVideo = {true}
          allowsInlineMediaPlayback = {true}
          allowFileAccess = {true}
        />
  );
};``` 

